# Is it possible to remove thumbnail of post on main page?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I know that probably you have answered this questions many times but I can’t use your advices in my case.

I have the Adelle theme by Blu Chic on my blog (right now I just test different functions and make changes before I move my blog on my own hosting). I made same changes in archive.php to change how posts displays in categories and archive.

```
   <div style="height:251px; display:block; margin:0 0 20px 0;"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(174,251), array('class' => 'alignleft'), $attr ); ?> </a><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();?> </a></h3>
```

```
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
```

I works but…during editing new post I have to set featured /thumbnail image. It’s not a problem. The problems show on first page because right now I have 2 images – one small and one big. Is it possible to remove thumbnail of post on main page?

I would be very grateful for your help!

Best,

Kasia

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is it on the single-post view or in the archive listing that the image is is showing up twice instead of once? Also, did this problem begin only after you made changes to the theme code? If so, seeing the 'before' and 'after' code sniipits might help in locating what happened.

Comment: Before I didnt have problem becasue I didnt have to use featured image. But because I want the have the excerpt and small photo in archive instead the full post I needed to start using featured image. I see two pictures on main page of blog - not in archive. I dont want thumbnail next to topic.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to find the CSS classes that belong to those thumbnail images on the main page and add a CSS property in the Additional CSS:

```
display: none
```

For screenshots you can check this guide: https://www.helpmegeek.com/remove-featured-thumbnails-list-pages-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement to use two images for your post, one on the main page that is archive page and other on post detail page, you can use one best plugin available for that

http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/

By using Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin you can see two featured images for your post, one you can display on main page and other on post detail page or whichever section you want to display.

Comment: Thanks...but I dont want to see thumbnails :) I want to have it only in archive/ category - nowhere else.

Comment: To remove the post thumbnails you can comment out the the_post_thumbnail(); from your theme files.

Comment: But how? :) I have only something like that: in functions.php. // Post thumbnail
  // ==================================================================
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size( 'post_thumb', 300, 200, true );  I dont see anything more which looks like relate to it. And I need thumbails in category/archive.

Comment: without seeing your files/code then we can't help any further. that code in theme functions just enables support for thumbnails in your wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the thumbnails just delete/comment out the php code that display the thumbnail like so:

```
<div style="height:251px; display:block; margin:0 0 20px 0;">
  <h3>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
       <?php //echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(174,251), array('class' => 'alignleft'), $attr ); ?>   <!-- Notice the  //  just after the first <?php tag
    </a> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title();?> 
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that I maybe didnt write it clearly. I want to see thumbnail in archive/category. That's why I wrote this code. I dont want to see it on the main page of my blog next to title. I dont know where I need to delete something from code :)

Comment: ok I see now, so you blog page, if it is not a custom one, will be single.php(for the individual post) and I believe page.php for the query list of recent posts.

Look for the   get_the_post_thumbnail(); on those pages and comment them out, don't delete them until you are happy it works correctly, so you can revert back if needed.

Comment: I can't find get_the_post_thumbnail() anywhere. I tried before I wrote  a question on this website. Code in page.php '<?php get_header(); ?>

  <section class="section" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="article" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

       <header class="post-header">
        <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      </header>
 
      <?php the_content(); ?>'

Comment: '
      <?php echo adelle_theme_get_link_pages() ?>

      <?php comments_template('/comments.php',true); ?>

    </article><!-- .article -->

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

  </section><!-- .section -->

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>'

Comment: Code in single.php is even shorter: '<?php get_header(); ?>

  <section class="section" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format()) ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); endif; ?>

  </section><!-- .section -->

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>'

Comment: http://ulubioneprzepisy.com/wp/ - you can see here what I want to remove - First picture of croissants.

Comment: yeeea :) I found  get_post_thumbnail in content-list.php. I deleted it and now main page looks like I want :) Thx all of you for your help. Best!